# Prove $|n^z| = |n^{\Re(z)}|$

Tags: complex-analysis

I was reading [these lecture notes](https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/%7Easbuch/complex_s18/NotesOnGammaZeta.pdf) and it's claimed at remark 2.2 (bottom of page 5) that for $n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus {0}$, and $z \in \mathbb{C}$,  $|n^z| = |n^{\Re(z)}|$, but I've not been able to prove it. Now in this context we also have that $\Re(z) > 1$, but that requirement doesn't help either. I get stuck around

$$
\begin{align*}
|n^z| &= |n^{x + iy}|\\\\
&= |\exp(z \text{Log}(n))|\\\\
&= |\exp(z \ln(n))|\\\\
&= |e^{x \ln(n)} (\cos(y \ln(n)) + i \sin(y \ln(n)))|,
\end{align*}
$$

(where $\text{Log}$ is the principal logarithm) and now because $\cos(y \ln(n)) + i \sin(y \ln(n))$ could be equal to 0, I'm not sure how to continue.

Comment: Hint: try using $n^{x+iy}=n^{x}n^{iy}$ and $|z_1z_2|=|z_1||z_2|$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> because $\cos(y\ln(n))+i\sin(y\ln(n))$ could be equal to 0

Why would this be true? $n$ is a positive number, so $y\ln(n)$ is a real number, and for any real number $r$, $\cos(r)+i\sin(r)$ has magnitude $1$. Ergo, we have:

$$
\begin{align*}
& |e^{x\ln(n)}(\cos(y\ln(n))+i\sin(y\ln(n)))| \\
= & |e^{x\ln(n)}| \\
= & |n^x| \\
= & |n^{\Re(x+iy)}| \\
= & |n^{\Re(z)}|
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: That's so obvious, no clue how I missed that. Thanks!